# How does clock gating in RTL design work?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, digital-logic, register-transfer-level, vlsi

I'm trying to understand how clock gating works in RTL design.

I've an example wave here:

[image]

Description:

```
1st signal is gated_clock
2nd signal is clock_enable
3rd signal is ungated_clock
```

So there are 3 cycles in this wave (let's say cycle 0,1,2). In cycle 0, clock_enable was low and gated_clock was turned off. In cycle 1 clock_enable goes high and in next cycle (cycle 2) gated_clock turns on.

Now, during simulation I see some cases where an incoming data received at cycle 1 is properly being registered into the module that is gated by the clock (using gated_clock). It's kinda odd to me and I don't quite understand how it's possible.

The logic is like this:

```
always_ff @(posedge gated_clock, negedge reset) begin
   if (~reset) begin
      some_val <= 1'b0;
   end else begin
      if (in_valid==1'b1 && in_ready==1'b1) begin
         some_val <= in_val;
      end else begin
         some_val <= 1'b0;
      end
   end
end
```

So I'm seeing that if `in_valid` and `in_ready` was high in `cycle 1` then `some_val` will register the incoming `in_val` data and it'll be available in `cycle 2`. However in `cycle 1`, `gated_clock` was zero. So how did the in_val get sampled here? From what I understand, posedge `gated_clock` must be 1 if we want to flop `in_val` in `cycle 1` .

I might be missing some core circuit level digital design concept. I'll really appreicate any help.

Updated wave:
[image]

```
1st signal is gated_clock
2nd signal is clock_enable
3rd signal is ungated_clock
4th signal is in_valid
5th signal is in_ready
6th signal is in_val
7th signal is some_val
```

So here you will see at `cycle 0`, `gated_clock` is off but `in_val` and `in_ready` is high. The input data `in_val` is also high. In next cycle `some_val` goes high. So it looks like `in_val` captured in `cycle 0` even though `gated_clock` was off.

Comment: Can you share code snippet for `gated_clock` generation?

Comment: waveforms of `in_val`, `in_valid`, `in_ready` and `some_val`, with a clock of `gated_clock` would be helpful (along with what you'd expect to see instead).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there is a glitch on the gated clock that's not showing up on the waveform. You'll need to look at the User Manual of the tool you're using to find out how to record and display glitches. It might also help to see the logic for gating the clock. Is clock_enable assigned using an NBA (<=)?

Comment: Yes, clock_enable is coming out from a flop.

Answer (score 1):

Your understand of *what* is clocked seemed off.  `in_val` isn't clocked here (actually, from the snippet, I can't see where it is coming from).  It is free to change at will (again, from the point of view of this snippet).  At the point that `gated_clock` goes high then whatever the value of `in_val` at that time will now be captured in `some_val` and this will be available until such time as `gated_clock` goes high again (at which point we will sample a new value).

Comment: Hi Dave, I added another wave. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @newbie: those waves confirm what I expected, and my answer stands.  If you don't understand it then ask for clarification.  But read it a few times first.  I'm still not sure what you expect to see instead of this behaviour.

Comment: Hi Dave, apprciate your feedback. I was not sure why we are flopping the value of some_val signal from cycle0 (new wave) even though the pos edge of gated clock at cycle 0 is zero. I think I lack proper understanding of how FF works. My assumption was to flop some_val from cycle0, the posedge of gated_clock aslo need to be high in cycle0 (not in cycle 1).

Comment: I found a good article explanining FF timing: http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4371393/Understanding-the-basics-of-setup-and-hold-time. So if I understood it properly, in my example when clock is low in cycle 0, some_val will be latched by the LHS latching circuit and eventually when gated_clock goes high in cycle1, the RHS latching circuit inside FF will drive the the captured data. I hope this is correct. Please correct me if I'm missing something again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new waveform `some_val` is generated correctly to the posted RTL. On the very first edge of `gated_clock` signals `in_valid` and `in_ready` are both high, thus `some_val` is going high too in that cycle. On the next edge it toggles back to low because `in_valid` goes low (and btw `in_val` too)